# Can we order different grid items into one grid

Tags: html, css, gridview

Suppose there is a parents grid and inside parent grid two more grids are there and inside that child grid and each one divided into 2 grid.
Now we had a hierarchy of grid
Parent---->> children----->>grandchildren

Now what I want to do is take children grid and exchange their .

Comment: This is what we consider to be a bad question. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide us with some codesamples and/or a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please complete the question too in addition to advise above

Comment: its too broad question.